# Interpolation between two values using python

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-3.6, interpolation

I am trying to perform a linear interpolation in Python from a graph which have coordinate values say (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). According to my values I will get a straight line in the graph [as in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ0pP.png)

My aim is at **10^6**(x-axis value) should give me the value of the parameter on y-axis but presently i am getting the extrapolate value not on the line.

Required Output:[OUtput needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9Ap.jpg)

I tried with below Code

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1, 10000000])
y = np.array([0.65, 0.25])
BK = np.asarray(np.interp(0.7,x,y))
print("aa:",BK)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(1000000,BK, marker="o",markersize=10)
plt.plot([1000000,1000000,0],[0,BK,BK], "b--", linewidth=1)
plt.xlim(1, 100000000)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
       
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are plotting a straight line in logarithmic space. Are you sure you want to interpolate that graphical line? Or do you want to interpolate the actual data?

Comment: I want to interpolate that graphical line

Comment: at 10^6 value i want to interpolate the graphical line and find the x-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the line drawn in the chart is completely unrelated to the data because it is a line in the chart, not in data coordinates. An interpolation of that line hence has zero meaning!

If you still want to interpolate that line you first need to transform to logspace:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1, 10000000])
y = np.array([0.65, 0.25])

xinp = 1e6
BK = np.asarray(np.interp(np.log(xinp), np.log(x), y))
print("aa:",BK)

plt.xscale("log")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xinp, BK, marker="o",markersize=10)
plt.plot([1000000,1000000,0],[0,BK,BK], "b--", linewidth=1)
plt.xlim(1, 100000000)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I understood the logic.Thank you very much